# REST Api filtering, sorting and order

Tags: rest, web-api

I've seen in several REST API guidelines recommendations to use filtering in form of, e.g.:

`/products?filter=name eq 'Milk' or price lt 2.55`

(example from: https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#971-filter-operations )

I tried to find a library that will help me to parse this kind of request (in .net/C#, but that's less relevant), but I hadn't find anything.

My question is: is this form of filtering really popular? If so, why there are no libs for it? Or it's just me who can't find them?

Second question: what are alternatives for "report like" filtering? I.e. complex UI that allows a user to select different criteria.

PS. I don't want OData. It's too invasive and goes straight to database (generates SQLs).

Comment: i think graphql is what you are looking for. https://graphql.org/ this approach has some downsides I wouldnt say its super popular, but there are def use cases for it

Comment: +1 for Graphql too